# UIDeviceRGBColor leak - how to fix?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks, three20, instruments

I am using the three20 library (not sure if this is the cause) and am getting a leak when going back and forth between two views of a navigation controller.

[image: Leaks]

More details of one of the leaks:

[image: Leak details]

The only think I can think of is that I show the toolbar when it pushes the second view onto the stack:

```
/**
 * View is going to appear
 *
 * @version $Revision: 0.1
 */
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}//end


/**
 * View will disappear
 *
 * @version $Revision: 0.1
 */
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}//end
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out where this is coming from. The extended detail stack trace is not showing any of my classes.

Where could this be coming from?

Comment: Dont knock three20, it has proven itself to be excellent in many of the stores tops apps. If you learn to use it right, like any other library, it becomes quite powerful, stable and saves a ton of dev time.

Comment: @coneybeare - I more than agree.

Comment: Still getting the issue in swift 4. Anyone know the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are customizing the navbar tint color, or any other colors, in one of the three20 stylesheets, make sure you are returning an autoreleased color.

Comment: I am not really using any three20 stylesheets.

Comment: Perhaps you should just grep your source code for UIColor instances then, and do some code inspection. I don't think this has to do with three20

Comment: Can you plz tell, What exactly this mean **make sure you are returning an autoreleased colour.**

Comment: @KumarKi This was answered in the days before ARC. If you are using modern memory management, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @coneybeare I use ARC but still get leaks

Comment: any update for the question of @KumarKL: `make sure you are returning an autoreleased colour.`(I got leaks with ARC too)?

Comment: same here with SLColorArt