# instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier leak

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, memory, memory-leaks

I am frustrated with this code...

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    DoctorRecordController *object=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DoctorRecord"];##############leaking code
    object.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:object animated:YES completion:^(void){            
    }];
```

instrument is showing a leak in above code.  How can I remove the leak?

Comment: What makes you so sure that (this specific object) is actually leaked? I just tested the same thing with no leaks at all. Can you post a screenshot of Instruments?

Answer (score 0):

You're capturing object perhaps in your block. try this:

```
object.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:object animated:YES completion:^(void){
    object = nil;
}];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried it but its showing an error like this Variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier)

Comment: try prepend `__block` to the type name of your variable declaration of `object`

Comment: i found somthing similar to what i have asked in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653771/uidevicergbcolor-leak-how-to-fix/5655441#5655441  but their he is not getting place where it is leaking , but for me its pointing to the particular code i have mentioned above in my question...

Answer (score 0):

by using __block  storage type modifier we can make object mutable [enter link description here http://kmithi.blogspot.de/2012/03/blocks-programming-in-ios.html](http://kmithi.blogspot.de/2012/03/blocks-programming-in-ios.html)